# Переписать функцию с js reduce на php

Tags: php, javascript

Переношу тяжёлый клиентский код на сервер и у меня возникли проблемы. Есть функция, написанная в JavaScript:

```
return Object.keys(locationData).reduce((prev, curr) => {
    var prevDistance = locationDistance(targetLocation, locationData[prev]),
        currDistance = locationDistance(targetLocation, locationData[curr]);
    return (prevDistance < currDistance) ? prev : curr;
});
```

Написал код на PHP:

```
function nearestsReduce($prev, $curr) {
    global $targetLocGlobal, $locationDataGlobal;
    $prevDistance = locationDistance($targetLocGlobal, $locationDataGlobal[$prev]);
    $currDistance = locationDistance($targetLocGlobal, $locationDataGlobal[$curr]);

    if($prevDistance < $currDistance) {
        return $prev;
    }
    return $curr;
}

function closestLocation($targetLocation, $locationData) {
    $all_keys = array_keys($locationData);
    return array_reduce($all_keys, 'nearestsReduce');
}
```

Собрал все ключи, отправил в функцию, а в самой функции уже выполняю всё то же, что и в JavaScript, но почему-то получаю ошибку:

> Notice: Undefined index: in

При чём, ошибка так и выводится - с пустым индексом. И я не могу понять, какой именно индекс не объявлен. Ошибка указывает на эту строку:

```
$prevDistance = locationDistance($targetLocGlobal, $locationDataGlobal[$prev]);
```

Answer (score 0):

В [документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-reduce.php) написано о первом параметре функции обратного вызова (ваша nearestsReduce) для array_reduce:

Содержит результирующее значение с предыдущей итерации; в случае же первой итерации содержит значение параметра initial.

initial - третий параметр array_reduce, он у вас не задан, и по умолчанию null. При первом же вызове вашей функции обратного вызова $prev получает значение null. Такой индекс в массиве locationDataGlobal не существует.

Comment: @And это вы вообще о чем? Где это я сказал, что функция должна быть первым аргументом?